# c++ class instance error lnk2019

Tags: c++

I searched for my problem for more than 3 hours but couldn't find any good articles about so decided to post a question here to ask for your advice. My problem is I don't understand how class works. It is just a simple class but in one case it doesn't work. First, below is the code that works

```
class R{
    int x, y;
public:
    R();
    R(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {};
    void setX(int a){ x = a; }
    void setY(int b){ y = b; }
    int getX(){ return x; }
    int getY(){ return y; }
    void display();
};
void R::display(){
// displaying x and y I removed the function because it somehow remove the rest of the code after arrow operator
}
int main(){
    R r(2,3);
    r.setX(1);
    r.setY(2);
    r.display();
}
```

but when I change the main like this it doesn't work

```
int main(){
    R r;
    r.setX(1);
    r.setY(2);
    r.display();
}
```

I first thought the reason might be that I didn't actually created an instance but found a code that works fine from a website. The code was like this:

```
// overloading operators example
#include 
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};

CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return temp;
}

int main () {
  CVector foo (3,1);
  CVector bar (1,2);
  CVector result;
  result = foo + bar;
// displaying x and y I removed the function because it somehow remove the rest of the code after arrow operator
  return 0;
}
```

It also just made an instance "CVector temp" not "CVector temp(2,3)" but it works fine while mine is not working.

If anyone knows what I am missing and the problem of my code, could you please give me your advice?

Thanks for reading and your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: What is the error text? "Unsresolved external symbol `<symbol>` in `<method>`..."

Comment: Okay, I found out that it works if I make the constructor definition with braces like "R(){};" but still don't get why it needs here. If anyone knows it, could you teach me?

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments!
@Max: I just noticed that some codes were unable to show when I typed << operators so modified it just right now. Um, but what do you mean the <symbol> and <method>?

@ πάντα ῥεῖ, thanks for your comment! I'm reading it now!

Comment: Because you need the default constructor, so you need a definition. Currently you only have a declaration. If it doesn't do anything, you can also remove it, and the compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: @June It's likely irrelevant; see my answer.

Comment: Also irrelevant, but please make main return 0.

Comment: Thank you juanchopanza, πάντα ῥεῖ, and Banex! All of your advice actually helped me out! I was able to fix and even make it better with your advice! I really appreciate all of you who gave me good advice since every advice here was definitely helpful! Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, I can surmise that the error is related to the missing definition of `R:: R ()`.

MSVC's `Error LNK2019` refers to an unresolved symbol. A symbol is any function, object, variable, or type which has been **declared** but not **defined**.

In this case, I'm guessing that you have never provided a definition for `R:: R ()`, but you wrote it in the class definition, which tells the compiler that it's there somewhere -- that's the declaration.

But, apparently, you never defined it. 
Adding `{}` provides the body of the function, which is why it works with those braces.

You could also define `R:: R()` as you did `R:: display ()`, externally, or, if your compiler supports C++11, write explicitly `R:: () = default`.

Once you give the linker a body of the function, your code should link fine.

Comment: Thank you very much Max!! It really solved my problem and that was the answer I'd like to know! Thank you! Somehow it says I need to check this answer after 2mins so after that, I'll check this as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you write it like

```
R();
```

it is a **Declaration** of the `constructor`. You have to give each method you use a **Definition** also by giving it a body (even if the body is empty like here). For class method, either you provide the body as you did here *inside* the class, or you can define it separately in a source (.cpp) file like

```
R::R(){/*your code*/}
```

it is similar to the code for
 `CVector CVector::operator+` as you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rakibul! Though Max's had good exaplanation but I think your answer is simple and good enough to understand so I'll promote it! Thank you for your answer! Now I feel much better!

Answer (score 1):

You NEED to have a default constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer armanali! Now I figured out I must actually give it a definition. Thank you!